# Apache Flink CEP how to pass in time window based on event value?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

```
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("start")
    .next("middle").where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(Event value) throws Exception {
            return value.getName().equals("error");
        }
    }).followedBy("end").where(new SimpleCondition<Event>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(Event value) throws Exception {
            return value.getName().equals("critical");
        }
    }).within(Time.seconds(10));
```

Is there a way I can replace `Time.seconds(10)` with `value.getSomeTimeField()` that I pass in through the `Event`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to work in event time manner. For more on it you can check out this [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_time.html) and [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html) section on how to extract timestamp from element.

In your example you can do sth like:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

DataStream<Event> input = ...

input.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Event>() {

    @Override
    public long extractAscendingTimestamp(MyEvent element) {
        return value.getSomeTimeField();
    }
})

CEP.pattern(input, pattern).select(...)
```

This way events will be automatically sorted in the stream and the timeout will be applied in both cases in regards to the time field.

Comment: So even without .within(...), this will trigger timeouts? Yes, the idea is that I don't want to hardcode the window e.g. not `Time.seconds(5)`, but it will be based on those set of events e.g. shipping a certain kind of parcel.

Comment: Ah, that changes it a bit, no unfortunately the value in `within` clause must be a stable value. It cannot be based on properties of events.